# Were the Clone Wars considered a total war?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

It is quite clear that the Clone Wars was a big event in the galactic history. Lots of people died and the outcome changed the entire galactic society.

But was it a total war, as was WW1 for France and Germany, where all production and resources were diverted to fuel the war? From what I could see the people away from the front could be totally unaware of the fight that is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, since not every planet was sending their resources to power the Republic/CIS war machine.  The various companies were profiting from both governments buying their equipment, and the IBC was profiting from interest on loans to both parties (though I'm kind of suspicious since they were allied with the CIS in Attack of the Clones).

Most of the work for the republic was handled by a mix of Bactoid and the Kaminoan cloners (though later on in the war extra facilities are created).

Also, this war was designed/orchestrated by Plagueis, Sidious, and Tyrannus.  It's designed to weaken different factions and planets to allow for Sidious to become Emperor and to wipe out the Jedi Order.

A better example of a total war would be one of the old republic wars, like the Mandalorian War or the Jedi Civil War, where resources were diverted away from typical uses to military uses.

Comment: Given the war being designed to achieve Sidious' goals, were there particular factions or worlds that greatly benefited or profited from the course of the war, without having to spend too much of their own resources? That seems like it would stand to reason - anyone who made money or consolidated power due to the Clone Wars would think Palpatine resolved things the right way - but I don't know if there are any examples of that.

Comment: @recognizer There were a few companies, mostly the ones that created the clone supplies that would eventually become storm trooper gear.